# Is there a way to add multiple constraint bounds in generic function in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there a way to add multiple type parameters for generic functions?

I have two data classes who have some fields the same, and I want to compare them with only one function. Something like this:

```
data class ClassA{
  val field: String?
  ...
}

data class ClassB{
  val field: String?
  ...
}
```

And generic function should be something like:

```
private fun <T> mapSomething(model: T): String
    where T : ClassA,
          T: ClassB {
    // do something with model.field and return String
}
```

But I get

> Only one of the upper bounds can be a class

Is there a way to have two classes as upper bounds?

Comment: Does this work for you? https://gist.github.com/FSIvan/c8bc5ac7c74ef5e7e9ff045bd00b2651

Comment: In my case not really but seems like nice idea. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that multiple type bounds (which use exactly this syntax) are connected by "and", not "or". So `T` would need to be a subtype of *both* `ClassA` and `ClassB`, which is of course impossible. And currently there's no way to do "or". In future Kotlin *might* get union types, which would let you write `T : ClassA | ClassB`, but I wouldn't expect

```
val x: ClassA | ClassB = ...
x.field
```

to work even then, instead you will probably have to

```
val x: ClassA | ClassB = ...
when(x) {
    is ClassA -> // use ClassA.field
    is ClassB -> // use ClassB.field
}
```

But if you own `ClassA` and `ClassB`, you can just add an interface:

```
interface HasField {
    val field: String?
}

data class ClassA : HasField {
  override val field: String?
  ...
}

data class ClassB : HasField {
  override val field: String?
  ...
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
private fun <T> mapSomething(model: T, getField: (T) -> String?): String {
    ...
}
```

and pass `ClassA::field` or `ClassB::field` respectively.